# How to get the URL of a Tumblr photoset iframe

Tags: iframe, tumblr

I am customizing my tumblr template and I need to access the URL of the iframe that contains my photoset. When I look at the html of my tumbler page, I see:

```
<figure class="photoset with-caption">
  <div id="photoset_66130132457" class="html_photoset">
    <iframe id="photoset_iframe_66130132457" class="photoset" style="border:0px; background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" src="http://blog.kazoova.com/post/66130132457/photoset_iframe/kazoova/tumblr_mvtbtjxyAt1t05bsz/0/false" frameborder="0" height="535" scrolling="no" width="100%">  
    </iframe>
   </div>
</figure>
```

How do I get the value of src in the iframe using tumblr variables?

I can get the URLs of individual images using the following code, but this is not what I am looking for:

```
{block:Photoset}
  {block:Photos}
    {PhotoURL-500}
  {/block:Photos}
{/block:Photoset}
```

I am hoping there is a variable for photoset that is similar to {PhotoURL-500} like {PhotosetURL-500}.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to get a Photosets iframe src

Sadly, there isn't a `theme operator` that gives us the `src` as a string, the only option we have is to use `{Photoset-500}` as OP states. However, it is possible to work the iframe src out with the `theme operators` we have.

#### Breakdown of the iframe src

```
http://mikedidthis-pierre.tumblr.com/post/37187983482/photoset_iframe/mikedidthis-pierre/tumblr_meih4y5SDi1rkq61e/700/false
```

We can break this down into 7 parts:

1. `http://mikedidthis-pierre.tumblr.com/post/`
2. `37187983482/`
3. `photoset_iframe/`
4. `mikedidthis-pierre/`
5. `tumblr_meih4y5SDi1rkq61e/`
6. `700/`
7. `/false`

*1* The URL of the Tumblr blog, prefixed with `post/`. 1 and 2 should be used in tandum.
*2* Unique Post ID.
*3* A generic, consistant sub directory.
*4* At first glance looks like the Tumblr username. I wouldn't say its the Tumblr URL due to custom domains. However, it seems like it can be changed to anything, as long at it contains a character.
*5* A unique Tumblr generated ID. Think reblog keys. This is the part we really need and there are no `theme operators` to generate this.
*6* The size, in width of the iframe.
*7* Shadow mode. I believe turning this to `true` adds drop shadows to each of the photos in a photoset.

#### How much of this can we replicate?

So using the available theme operators like so:

```
{BlogURL}/post/{PostID}/photoset_iframe/x/ * missing 5 * /700/false
```

We can almost generate the full src!

```
http://mikedidthis-pierre.tumblr.com/post/37187983482/photoset_iframe/x/ * missing 5 * /700/false
```

#### Finding 5

The bad news is, we are going to need javascript. I am not going to cover that, but I will explain how we can get the missing information. If you use the `theme operators` for a photoset, that just give use the image urls `{PhotoURL-500}:

```
http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_meih4y5SDi1rkq61eo4_500.jpg
```

Can you see 5? Lets break it down:

1. `http://25.media.tumblr.com/`
2. `tumblr_meih4y5SDi1rkq61e`
3. `o4`
4. `_500`
5. `.jpg`

*1* Address for the Tumblr server the image is hosted on.
*2* The missing data 5.
*3* This is the number of the image in the photoset, so 4th. However, I think this relates to upload order, rather than display order.
*4* Size of the image.
*5* File extension.

#### So now what?

So to get the complete iframe src, you are going to need to use javscript to find the data for part 5 and then combining that with the data we already have from the available `theme operators`.

OP hasn't stated why they need the iframe URL. I would presume for delaying the loading, maybe to do with responsive.

Hope it helps!

#### Proof of concept:

Image based Photoset: [Example](http://mikedidthis-pierre.tumblr.com/post/37187983482/android-wallpapers-some-great-wallpapers-for-your).

Iframe based Photoset using information from above: [Example](http://mikedidthis-pierre.tumblr.com/post/37187983482/photoset_iframe/x/tumblr_meih4y5SDi1rkq61e/700/false).

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Your answer is very well written, clear and detailed. Thanks again.

Comment: @soo-ling My pleasure. It was fun to answer! Can I ask why you needed the iframe src?

Comment: It was a very silly reason....I am almost embarrassed to say it now....Here goes: I wanted to get Pinterest to work on photosets: so when the pin it button is clicked, users can select an image from all the images from a photoset to pin, but after putting in the code provided by Pinterest and providing the URL of the blog post, it extracts nothing. I thought if I gave it the iframe src it would work. But after all that, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know how to get the Pin It button to work on Photosets? (I can create a new question since it is different from this one.)

Comment: @soo-ling Nothing embarrassing about that at all. If you add the question, I will answer what I know. (iirc, its only possible to pass in the last image in a photoset, but I should look again)

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful! I have just added the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859140/how-to-get-pinterest-widget-to-extract-images-of-a-photoset-in-blog-post-and-ind

Comment: @soo-ling No problem, leave it with me, its a pretty long answer, so I will try my best to add it in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Many thanks! Can't wait to get the Pinterest button working :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - I wanted to link the photoset "captions" (headers the way we have it set up) so that all of the post headers were links and worked/looked the same.

I found [@mikedidthis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2312574/mikedidthis)'s answer helpful. But I played around with it a bit and I thought reconstruction the `iframe` `src` from scratch was overkill.

I went about it updating my markup with a few more classes and using the following Javascript -

```
$('.top.media.photoset.no-link').each(function(){
    $set = $(this);
    var url = $set.find('iframe').attr('src');
    // console.log(url);
    $set.find('.cont').find('a').attr('href',url).end().end().removeClass('no-link');                           
});
```

Since I have lazy loading on, I wanted a way to only set the `href` once per link, I added in the class `no-link` to use for selector specificity (I could have also searched for links where href != "#" as well I suppose).