# Tumblr: How to get Pinterest Widget to extract images of a photoset in Blog Post and Index Page

Tags: tumblr

I would like to get the Pin It button to work on photosets: so when the pin it button is clicked, users can select an image from all the images from a photoset to pin. I am using the code provided by Pinterest widget generator and adding in tumblr variables as follows:

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={URLEncodedPermalink}" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" ><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a>
```

But when clicked it says "Sorry, couldn't find any pinnable things on this page." (You can see an example here: http://blog.kazoova.com/post/66130132457/driver-tuition-with-mike-cooper) Of course it would be ideal if I can get all images, but if not, even getting 1 image would be great too!

The other problem I notice is: on the index page of my blog (http://blog.kazoova.com/), if I click on the Pinterest widget, it returns me the image and description for the index page, rather than images for the specific blog post. How do I make it return me the images of a specific blog in the index page?

Many thanks for your help.